# Error with ruby script in windows platform

Tags: ruby

I want to run ruby code in windows 10 platform. I have already installed ruby (rubyinstaller-devkit-2.4.5-1-x64) and tried to run on command prompt, but I got errors on my result. Previously it worked fine on terminal (MAC). Can someone help me on this? Thank you very much

```
Dir. for each ($path + "/input/") do |entry|
    if entry.match(/.*osc$/)
        fix_missing_logo(entry)
        process(entry)
    FileUtils.move $path + "/input/" + entry, $path + "/backup/"
    end
```

error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): convert.rb:332:in `<main>':
>   undefined method`each' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Comment: A) It's a "Mac", not a [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) which is something entirely different. B) Always have a good Ruby language reference open so you can double-check your code before running it. There's nothing wrong with getting a second opinion on something. C) This code isn't valid Ruby so it shouldn't work on either system in this form.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how `Dir` works. It should be calling [`each`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Dir.html#method-i-each) like this:

```
Dir.new($path + "/input/").each do |entry|
  # ...
end
```

As a note, please try and stay away from global variables. In Ruby `$` means global variable, it's not like PHP where that means just any old variable. Global variables cause all sorts of problems, like their origin and ownership being unclear, and of name collisions.